# Getting error when i logout, No AuthenticationScheme was specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

working on a small asp.net mvc project there i know got the login and registerform complete. But i got a litle bit problem with my signout/logout buton,

Im getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
> there was no DefaultSignOutScheme found. The default schemes can be
> set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
> AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

And my controller Logout looks like this,

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SDApi.SessionToken, "");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

It says that my code is wrong on ,

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

You got any clue what might be wrong here or what iam missing :)? following a tutorial and i made exactly the same thing...

Comment: Still need help if anyone know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this after days of head scratching.
In your Program.cs, dont forget to add DefaultScheme...  I will copy and paste my code that helped me.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication
    (options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
              .AddCookie(options =>
              {
                  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                  options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                  options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
                  options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied";
                  options.SlidingExpiration = true;
              });
```